# AVR CTC mode: Output Compare B Match Interrupt Not working

Tags: timer, avr

I am learning AVR programming using a book named" Make: AVR programming". I was trying to understand Timer peripheral. What following program does is toggling a pin at a certain interval using interrupt

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

// initialize timer, interrupt and variable
void timer1_init()
{
    // set up timer with prescaler = 64 and CTC mode
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12)|(1 << CS11)|(1 << CS10);

    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1B);        // Output Compare B Match Interrupt Enable
    // initialize counter
    TCNT1 = 0;

    // initialize compare value
    OCR1B = 7812;
    sei();
}


ISR(TIMER1_COMPB_vect) { 
    PORTC ^= (1 << 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    // connect led to pin PC0
    DDRC = 0XFF;

    // initialize timer
    timer1_init();

    // loop forever
    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

But it's not toggling the pin, Why?

Answer (score 1):

Which micro controller do you use?

One problem i can spot is the missing initialization of the `OCR1A` that sets the top of the counter so your counter does never count up to your compare value because by default `OCR1A` is zero.

So maybe you should write to `OCR1A` instead of `OCR1B`.

one tip:
the newer avr-cores support pin-toggeling by a simple write to the pin-register (look at data sheets the I/O-Ports section). this saves some cycles for the read and the `xor`. So `PORTC ^= (1 << 0);` is equivalent to `PINC = (1<<0);`

Comment: AtMega168. Missing OCR1A was the issue. What I thought was, When TCNT matches with OCR1A, channel A match interrupt fires, and When matches with OCR1A, channel B match interrupt fires. Which is only partially TRUE. I haven't understood the concept that OCR1A sets the frequency. Without setting it's default value will be 0, and OCR1B never reaches.Also  If I have set TCCR1A to toggle OC0A & OC0B on match, OCR1A sets the frequency for both OC1A & OC1B, and OC1A toggles upon match with OCR1A which is also the TOP, and OC1B toggles when match occurs with OCR1B, Right?? I will try your tip